# Переделать админку на https

Tags: php, https

Есть сайт, там что фронт что бэк на http 
Можно ли как то не хитро и быстро сделать админку на защищенном https 
Сайт на php

Comment: А в чем проблема? Простой редирект, не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно нужно просто настроить веб-сервер, ничего переписывать не нужно. Рекомендую все-таки узнать что такое [HTTPS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

Переход к защищенному HTTPS протоколу делается на уровне веб сервера.

Если вы используете Nginx - лучше воспользоватся директивой return код_состояния url. Перенаправление лучше выполнять на уровне location, чтобы файлы robots.txt и sitemap.xml остались доступными для поисковых систем. Контекст с http:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name domain.tld;
  server_name www.domain.tld;

  location ^/robots.txt {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
  location ^/sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
  }
}
```

В рамках контекста http желательно включить компрессию:

```
gzip on;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss     text/javascript;
gzip_disable "msie6";
```

---

Вам также может помочь статья Nginx. [Переход с http на https](https://www.influunt.ru/nginx-switch-from-http-to-https).